# Doughnut graph using SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I need to replicate this doughnut graph:

[image]

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666584/how-to-build-this-rounded-two-tone-donut-chart) question and played with the solution given but I haven't been able to get good progress as I have no experience whatsoever in SVG. But this shows what I did so far. ([link here to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suika/uuuyaoqt/))

```
<svg width="600" height="600">
    <defs>
        <mask id="innerbevel">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="235" fill="white"/>
        </mask>

        <mask id="centrehole">
            <rect x="-100%" y="-100%" width="200%" height="200%" fill="white"/>
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="195" fill="black"/>
        </mask>

        <linearGradient id="grad1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#2188cb"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="##2188cb" stop-opacity="0" />
            </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g transform="translate(300,300)" mask="url(#centrehole)">
        <g>
            <path d="M0 0 0 -275 A 275 275 0 0 1 0 275" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
            <path d="M0 0 0 275 A 275 275 0 0 1 -275 0" fill="#a6a6a6"/>
            <path d="M0 0 -275 0 A 275 275 0 0 1 0 -275" fill="#a6a6a6"/>

            <circle cx="0" cy="235" r="40" fill="#2188cb"/>
            <circle cx="-235" cy="0" r="40" fill="#a6a6a6"/>
            <circle cx="0" cy="-235" r="40" fill="#a6a6a6"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The graph is originally divided into three and since I couldn't work around it I thought about just setting the same color to the second and last path.. The gradient wasn't also very nice.. And I couldn't easily change the "percentage" of the graph.

PS: the text is only a dummy text, I know it's not 75% on the image. And yes, my work is a mess.

Help, anyone?

Edit:
Question is how do I make it only two paths with the closest division as with the image I am replicating? I don't quite get how the paths are set, as well as how to correctly set the gradient to follow the path because right now it's linear.

Comment: What is the question here? If it's about improving the code then this is the wrong place for it.

Comment: How is this different from the original stackoverflow link I just linked? I'm trying to replicate a design, I did research, provided my work so far, and asked for help. :/

Comment: You haven't clearly stated what your problem is. All you've said is "I'm trying to replicate this graph, and this is what I have done so far".  What is your question?

Comment: As for that original llnk, it was lucky to get answered at all...it should have been closed...it's not even close to meeting SO's question standards.

Comment: Yeah I get the problem now, wrong move to base my question to a wrong example. I edited my question now if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much simpler version:

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#05a"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0a5"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="200" stroke="grey" stroke-width="50" fill="none"/>
  <path d="M 250,50 A 200 200 0 1 1 250 450 A 200 200 0 1 1 250 50"
        stroke="url(#linear)" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="50"
        fill="none" stroke-dasharray="750,1256" />
</svg>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/ywus1z14/2/

[image]

The only thing that needs to change to make it "grow" is the first value of `stroke-dasharray` which should be `x * circumference`. Here, `circumference` is about 1256 (2 * radius=200 * pi).

**EDIT**

Just for fun, another version that uses a combination of `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`, set via CSS, and animated:

https://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/ywus1z14/1/

Comment: Wow this is really helpful, thank you. Although I have to ask, how can I make the edges of the paths circular? I understand that on my code it is separately drawn apart from the path, but on your code it's not like that. On the screenshot you also gave, it has rounded edges but on the fiddle it's not?

Comment: Firefox apparently has trouble with rounded line-ups on circles. Updated to use a path instead of a circle.

Comment: Oh so that's why. Thank you so much for this! I really appreciate it you saved my life. Anyway I found tricks on how to rescale/resize svg's dimensions but was wondering if there was anything simpler by modifying some of your codes in here instead of css?

Comment: Just change the coordinates/sizes in the SVG. There are very few of them, so you should be able to figure out what is what and how to adjust them. Or you can add a transform to scale it, either in the SVG or via CSS.

Comment: Used transform to scale it down, here's the final output: https://jsfiddle.net/suika/ywus1z14/4/ Thanks again!

Comment: Is "transparent" an unofficial but widely used keyword? It doesn't appear to be on the list of W3C SVG colors, and you'd normally use "none". How is it different from none?

Comment: Per the specification, SVG also accepts CSS colors. The spec references CSS2 which did not have `transparent` as a color, but as a keyword, however later versions of CSS consider it an actual color. So I guess it is not per se 100% correct, but it seems to be widely accepted. I'll update the code to be compliant.